# How to have fluid height in css?

Tags: css, responsive-design, percentage, fluid

I'm trying to make slide down effect on some items, on hover the image will slide down and show the content, the problem is when you resize the browser the images resize too because I have

`img { max-width: 100%; }`

but the problem is I can't have a fluid height too, I can't use percentage height on them.
This is what's happening:

http://codepen.io/joe/pen/yLjEx

I set the background as black to see what's happening, and I currently have height 210px.

So how can fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across this similar issue in my work.  Unfortunately there is no clean solution with just CSS.  You can use some javascript that will fire during the `onresize` event or you can add a placeholder image that is unseen and will keep the `div`'s resizing in the correct ratio.

What I did was make the `.desc` positioned absolutely above a copy of the balloon image which "holds the the shape" of the `div`.  You can use a transparent `.png` or just set the image to `opacity:0.0;` like in my codepen.  See my example including the middle `<li>` which is scrollable.

[Foreked codepen w/ auto-resize height and scrolling](http://codepen.io/djfarrelly/pen/wevfb)

**Note:** To work cross browser this would require more testing and possible use of IE's `filter` to make the image transparent.

Answer (score 0):

add `min-width:300px;` (300px can be switched out for whatever size you want), to the img {}.  So you would have `img { max-width: 100%; min-width:300px;}`.  That should keep the text from running out under the image.

[Forked codepen with the 300px added.](http://codepen.io/m0ose89/pen/rqyjC)

Comment: yes I'm aware of that but I want the image to resize, and the height 210px on the li is only for demonstration.